# nuxt 2.15.7 is installed by default while creating nuxt app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to create a nuxt app (version 3) in vue and when I enter the command `npm create nuxt-app@version mousa` it installs nuxt2 by default.

How to install nuxt3 with this command?

Answer (score 0):

`npx nuxi init nuxt-app` is the CLI command to run for a Nuxt3 app as shown here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/quick-start#new-project

`create-nuxt-app` is only for Nuxt2 apps. Nuxi is the way to go for Nuxt3.

Comment: Yes, but after installing with this command, the project runs successfully, but when I run the project, I get an error in the images and I don't see any changes in the code.

Comment: @MohammadGhiasvand having more details there would be welcome. Please edit your question with some relevant code snippet or a [repro].